# How to get help text on sub-commands?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, man

I am looking for a way to bring help text on sub commands such as `apt list`.

For example, if I write `apt --help`, I am getting:

> apt 1.2.26 (amd64) Usage: apt [options] command
>
> apt is a commandline package manager and provides commands for
>   searching and managing as well as querying information about packages.
>   It provides the same functionality as the specialized APT tools, like
>   apt-get and apt-cache, but enables options more suitable for
>   interactive use by default.
>
> Most used commands:
>   list - list packages based on package names
>   search - search in package descriptions

And I would like to go deeper, and get help on `apt list`. If I try `apt list --help`, I am getting same exact help text of `apt --help`. I know `list` command supports `apt list --upgradable` parameter, but I could not see how to show it in the help text.

Any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `apt` manual:

```
list (work-in-progress)
    list is somewhat similar to dpkg-query --list in that it can
    display a list of packages satisfying certain criteria. It supports
    glob(7) patterns for matching package names as well as options to
    list installed (--installed), upgradeable (--upgradeable) or all
    available (--all-versions) versions.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a way to bring help text on sub commands such as apt list.

Typically one would consult the `man` page for the command

`man apt` gives information on  `apt list` as well as the other ways to interact with `apt`.